# Angled CSS Separator

Tags: css, separator, divider, css-shapes

Please see the below image...

[image]

---

I would like to make this via CSS.

I'm using this separator now as an image ( jpg ) that is responsive inside my container. The problem is that I can't seem to match colors exactly or get the white crystal clear and sharp.

I think CSS would be best way to solve this problem.

The dimensions are 1170px x 100px

Using Bootstrap 3.2

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/separator.gif">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need that as a background or a content separator?

Comment: Alternatively, this image would really look sharper if you saved it as a .gif instead of a .jpg

Comment: What you have done so far? share your code.

Answer (score 4):

**Using SVG:** <sup>**Recommended**</sup>

You could make use of SVG to create the shape. Since it is a separator (which implies, it is not going to contain any text within the shape), it is more like an image and SVG fits the case perfectly. SVG can auto-scale without having any impact to the actual shape and since it is vector based, it doesn't get pixelated on scaling either.

We can use either SVG `path` or `polygons` to create this shape. Below are the sample snippets.

```js
/* Using SVG Path */
```

```css
svg {
  height: 100px;
  width: 1170px;
}
path#top {
  fill: rgb(218, 115, 23);
}
path#bottom {
  fill: rgb(42, 42, 42);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
  <path d='m 0,0 h 100 l -100,95z' id='top' />
  <path d='m 0,100 h 100 l 0,-90z' id='bottom' />
</svg>
```

```js
/* Using SVG Polygons */
```

```css
svg {
  height: 100px;
  width: 1170px;
}
polygon#top {
  fill: rgb(218, 115, 23);
}
polygon#bottom {
  fill: rgb(42, 42, 42);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
  <polygon points='0,0 100,0 0,95' id='top' />
  <polygon points='0,100 100,100 100,10' id='bottom' />
</svg>
```

---

**Using Gradients:**

You could achieve the shape by using two `linear-gradient` for background and position them appropriately like in the below snippet. Linear gradients can scale without affecting the shape.

```css
.separator {
  height: 100px;
  width: 1170px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 49%, rgb(218, 115, 23) 50%), 
    linear-gradient(to top left, rgb(42, 42, 42) 49%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
  background-size: 100% 95%, 100% 90%;
  background-position: 0% 0%, 0% 90%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="separator"></div>
```

> None of the approaches produce a perfectly smooth output for the white colored area in the middle. While SVG produces more smoother edges, gradients produce a very rough/coarse output.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1 :** with borders with `vw` units :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hmLexg0w/)** (credits to [Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry) for the demo)

```css
.separator{
    width:95vw;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.separator:before, .separator:after{
    content:'';
    display:block;
}
.separator:before{
    border-left: 95vw solid #DA7317;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right:0;
    border-top:0;
}
.separator:after{
    border-right: 95vw solid #000;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left:0;
    border-bottom:0;
    margin-top:-45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="separator">
</div>
```

**Solution 2:** with transform rotate :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6mxxdw0w/1/)**

```css
.separator{
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:5.5%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.separator:before, .separator:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
}
.separator:before{
    background: #DA7317;
    bottom:100%; left:-1%;
    width:101%; height:200%;
    
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);    
}
.separator:after{
    background: #000;
    top:100%;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-2.5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-2.5deg);
    transform: rotate(-2.5deg);  
}
```

```html
<div class="separator"></div>
```

Comment: I tried something similar a couple of days back but the catch seems to be that the diagonal line's width varies from one end to the other. I guess, that white separator also needs to be another triangle (sort of).

Comment: Actually even a triangle wasn't needed for the separator. Minor adjustments to border width and margin were enough. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hmLexg0w/) is a forked version of your original answer. Please feel free to use it.

Comment: nice catch @Harry, I didn't notice that the white line doesn't have the same thickness all along. Thx for the demo :)

Comment: Thanks guys. The second demo ( using transform rotate ) I will try out later tonight as the white bar seems much less jagged. Will advise if I run into any problems placing within my container. Thanks again!